# How do I convert these coordinates to coordinates readable by Google Maps?

Tags: php, google-maps, coordinates

Take a look at the map coordinates on this [page](http://stable.toolserver.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Area_51&params=37_14_06_N_115_48_40_W_type:airport). This is linked in from Wikipedia and the coordinates are passed the query string. I'm not sure of the actual terms for this but How do I convert the coordinates? They look like this:

**37° 14′ 6″ N, 115° 48′ 40″ W**

I would like them to look like this:

**37.235, -115.811111**

, which is a format readable by Google maps, as seen in [this example](http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=37.235,-115.811111&spn=0.03,0.03&t=m&q=37.235,-115.811111).

How do I do this in PHP, and what are the two different types of coordinates called?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The original format is in hours, minutes, seconds format. To convert to decimal, do:

D = H + M/60 + s/3600

So in your example, 37,14,6 becomes

37 + 14/60 + 6/3600 = 37.235, as stated.

If the latitude is N the result is positive, if S, negative.
If the longitude is E the result is positive. If west the result is negative.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html) is the Javascript function that does what you are talking about.

> This utility permits the user to convert latitude and longitude
>   between decimal degrees and degrees, minutes, and seconds. For
>   convenience, a link is included to the National Geodetic Survey's
>   NADCON program, which allows conversions between the NAD83 / WGS84
>   coordinate system and the older NAD27 coordinate system. NAD27
>   coordinates are presently used for broadcast authorizations and
>   applications.
>
> This utility requires that Javascript be enabled to perform the
>   calculations.

Answer (score 0):

My PHP Code from this Post, Thank You!

```
function GetLatLon_FromExif($GPS){
$Lat_Ref = $GPS['GPSLatitudeRef'];
if($Lat_Ref == "S") { $Lat_Neg = "-"; }
$Lat_H = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLatitude']['0'])[0];
$Lat_M = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLatitude']['1'])[0];
$Lat_S = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLatitude']['2'])[0];
$Lat_S2 = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLatitude']['2'])[1];

$Lon_Ref = $GPS['GPSLongitudeRef'];
if($Lon_Ref == "W") { $Lon_Neg = "-"; }
$Lon_H = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLongitude']['0'])[0];
$Lon_M = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLongitude']['1'])[0];
$Lon_S = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLongitude']['2'])[0];
$Lon_S2 = explode("/" ,$GPS['GPSLongitude']['2'])[1];

$Lat = $Lat_H+($Lat_M/60)+(($Lat_S/$Lat_S2)/3600);
$Lon = $Lon_H+($Lon_M/60)+(($Lon_S/$Lon_S2)/3600);

return $Lat_Neg.$Lat.",".$Lon_Neg.$Lon;
}
```

---

JSON (from IMAGE EXIF):

```
"GPS": {
  "GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
  "GPSLatitude": [
    "22/1",
    "15/1",
    "1708/100"
  ],
  "GPSLongitudeRef": "W",
  "GPSLongitude": [
    "97/1",
    "52/1",
    "1882/100"
  ],
  "GPSAltitudeRef": "\u0000",
  "GPSAltitude": "9364/369",
  "GPSSpeedRef": "K",
  "GPSSpeed": "2203/12629",
  "GPSImgDirectionRef": "T",
  "GPSImgDirection": "52751/159",
  "GPSDestBearingRef": "T",
  "GPSDestBearing": "52751/159",
  "UndefinedTag:0x001F": "6625/828"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Umm the page you mention already gives you the coordinates in WGS84 and in Latitude Longitude format

Comment: Yeah I know that but I just want a formula to get the latitude and longitude from the coordinates - WGS84 as you said format. Or a function in Php would be even nicer :)