# how to convert between degrees, minutes, seconds to Decimal coordinates

Tags: java, geolocation, geospatial, geotools

Looking for a java utility. It is even better if you can tell me how to do it using geotools library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert these coordinates to coordinates readable by Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995738/how-do-i-convert-these-coordinates-to-coordinates-readable-by-google-maps)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By "Decimal coordinates" do you mean latitude and longitude (also known as the decimal degree)? If so, what you're trying to do is pretty easy:

> Given a DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds) coordinate such as W87°43′41″,
>   it's trivial to convert it to a number of decimal degrees using the
>   following method:
>        Calculate the total number of seconds, `43′41″ = (43*60 + 41) = 2621` seconds. The fractional part is total number of seconds divided
>   by 3600. 2621 / 3600 = ~0.728056 Add fractional degrees to whole
>   degrees to produce the final result: 87 + 0.728056 = 87.728056
>
> Since it is a West longitude coordinate, negate the result.
>           The final result is -87.728056.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion). Here's a [Javascript widget](http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html) that does the same thing.

Answer (score 23):

It depends on your source format.  If it's already split up into degrees (d), minutes (m), and seconds (s), your algorithm is:

(assuming d is can be positive or negative)

```
dd = Math.signum(d) * (Math.abs(d) + (m / 60.0) + (s / 3600.0));
```

If it's smooshed together into a string, the usual format is:

"ddd.mmss"

So parse out using a regular expression or String.substring() to get m and s.

Converting back is:

```
d = (int)dd;  // Truncate the decimals
t1 = (dd - d) * 60;
m = (int)t1;
s = (t1 - m) * 60;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
**begin  23°26’49”**
degrees = 23
minutes = 26
seconds = 49
decimal = ((minutes * 60)+seconds) / (60*60))
answer = degrees + decimal
**finish  23.44694444**
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested on http://www.sunearthtools.com/dp/tools/conversion.php and it works

Answer (score 0):

TLDR

```
fun getNormal(value: String): Double {
    val degree = value.substringBefore("°").toDouble()
    val minute = value.substringAfter("°").substringBefore("'").toDouble()
    val second = value.substringAfter("'").trim().toDouble()
    return sign(degree) * (abs(degree) + (minute / 60.0) + (second / 3600.0))
}
```

getNormal("34° 31' 24.924") returns 34.52359