# Convert WGS84(Degrees, Minutes, seconds) To Decimal Degrees

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert between degrees, minutes, seconds to Decimal coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263959/how-to-convert-between-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-coordinates)

I have **39°07.356"N** and **121°02.482"W** and i need to convert it to Decimal Degrees.
any source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263959/how-to-convert-between-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to perform the task

```
public decimal DmsToDD(double d, double m = 0, double s = 0)
{
    return Convert.ToDecimal((d + (m/60) + (s/3600))*(d < 0 ? -1 : 1));
}
```

Of course, you'll need to check to make sure the minute and second components are non-negative before you do the conversion.