# How to pass latitude and longitude from minute decimals to degrees?

Tags: java

I have latitude and longitude measured in minute decimals, e.g.:

```
double lat = 3198.183333;
double lon = -387.316667;
```

I need to convert these values into degrees like, e.g. lat 40.18. 
Taking into account that there are 360° of longitude (180° E <-> 180° W) and 180° of latitude (90° N <-> 90° S), and that each degree can be broken into 60 minutes (’), do I understand correctly that the only thing I should do is to divide my values by 60?:

```
double lat_degrees = 3198.183333/60;
double lon_degrees = -387.316667/60;
```

Comment: Correct. That's how you convert minutes to degrees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert between degrees, minutes, seconds to Decimal coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263959/how-to-convert-between-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-coordinates)