# How to calculate the distance between two pairs of coordinates (latitude/longitude)

Tags: latitude-longitude

So for example, I have two pairs of coordinates: (103.82 W, 32.024 N)  and (104.2 W, 32.587 N). I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the distance between these two points and then represent that distance in DMS form. When I use the distance formula, I obtain a decimal number that does not accurately represent my desired number when I convert it to DMS format. I'm supposed to use the distance formula, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here or what I could be doing wrong. I don't believe I need to use the haversine formula for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a coding question? What language are you using? What have you tried, where is your code or pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

The [Rosetta Code web site](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) has working code examples in various computer languages (Java, JavaScript, Python, and many others) to compute the distance between two lat/lon coordinates using the Haversine formula.

You can verify your distance results using this [online distance calculator](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for comparison.

Given a coordinate in decimal degrees you can convert that number into the DMS components or vice versa. The formula has been answered in a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263959/how-to-convert-between-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-coordinates) and there are [online converters](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal) to convert between DMS and decimal degrees.